# Python bot telegram

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm building a Telegram bot which tracks Amazon prices. Now, I have a problem because when I launch it on a raspberry pi (python3 name.py) it doesn't work. I'm trying to fix it but i cannot find the error (it isn't a syntax error). Here there's the code, if someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: I would be easier to help you if you could post the exact error you are getting (and at which line) in the post. If you are not getting an error, then please explain what is going wrong.

Comment: If you have faced problems in catching error, consider using debugger to go through your code. Please take a look at docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: it's not properly an error. It doesn't work beacause when i launch it it says: pi@raspberrypi: $ and i can type other things so it doesn't work

Comment: There has to be an error. Nobody can help you with "It doesn't work".

Comment: I mean, usually when it works on a raspberry when you click enter after 'python3 name.py' it do nothing and it means that there aren't problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the telepot/beautifulsoup4/requests package into the raspberry pi? If not then https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md